# How to choose a firmware before downgrading Andriod version?

Tags: downgrade

I have a Note4 which was shipped from the UAE (but I don't live in UAE). The current version of the device is 6.0.1 and I want to downgrade it to 4.4.4 (the stock version). I am having some trouble selecting the right firmware and was hoping if someone could help.

I came across this: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-N910C/XSG/ but I don't know which version to choose. My phone's baseband version (N910CXXU1DPC1) is not listed here.

Can I choose any 4.4.4 version and hope it will work on my phone ?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](https://samsung-firmware.org/download/GALAXY-Note4/q770/XEO/N910CXXU2DPCB/N910COXA2DPCB/), this is for Region XEO, which would be Poland, located [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-N910C/XEO/).  You can't just choose any version and have it work, and Samsung is known to not allow you going backwards in firmware versions due to a lock in the bootloader preventing this.  You may be able to go back to 5.1.1, but most likely not 2 Android versions backwards, and even going back to 5.1.1 may not be possible.

Comment: I was just about to say the same about bootloader, but after a brief search it looks like crossing the line between KitKat and Lollipop on this phone is possible without any extra steps. Still advise caution for OP.

Comment: Thx RMarkwald. That confused me even more. In the "About device" section I see the country as UAE. Shall I try to downgrade to 5.1.1 ? Can I use Kies to recover my phone in case I run into issues ?

Comment: That is totally up to you if you want to try to downgrade.  Personally, I wouldn't do it.  The only times I've flashed things were using Odin to do so.  I've never used Kies, I've always flashed the device and set it up from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

As long as downgrading itself is possible and the firmware is of the right model, firmware from any region will work, you just get a different set of preinstalled stuff and slightly tweaked modem for the corresponding region. This is why I always go for European (XX) firmwares - they're simply cleaner and still work.

Comment: Thank you Andy. Can you suggest me a European firmware for 5.1.1 (english version) which will work on my phone ?

Comment: Like I said, _anything_ as long as it's the same model. I just search for "XX" in the list and grab the one whose PDA version (the last 3 letters in the version) is the latest. Also, don't use Kies - backup and use Odin as instructed.